# Manhua in which the main character is reincarnated in a man's body and wakes up beside a sleeping princess

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

From what I remember, the main character (MC) reincarnated in a man's body. The man was actually a useless person, because he was always drinking and playing with women.

When the MC wakes up, he looks bad because of poison. Suddenly, a system appeared. The system helped the MC to recover the body. When he can get up, he sees a pretty girl sleeping beside him. The MC and the girl wear red dress where actually the girl and the man were about to be married. The girl is actually a princess but she looks like dead. The system says the MC can save the princess.

When the MC is about to save the princess, the empress (who is the princess' mother) came to see him try to open the princess' dress. The empress came with some people, I think the princess' female cousin and her mother. The evil one is the female cousin and her mother, who wants to be an empress. Because the one who actually poisoned the MC is the female cousin.

Another thing I remember is that, after saving the princess, the MC asks the female cousin where is the twin female attendant. The twin female attendant has been sold by the female cousin to an auction.